# Git не принимает пароль авторизации по https

Tags: git, ssh, putty

Нужно сделать *pull* из приватного репозитория по *https*.
Эту операцию нужно проделать на хостинге, подключаюсь через *putty* по *ssh*.

Набираю команду:

```
git pull bitbucket master
```

Просит ввести пароль:

```
Password for 'https://tatarinov@bitbucket.org':
```

Ввожу, но по нажатию <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> происходит переход на другую строку. И пароль вводится в отрытом виде, т. е. я его вижу, когда печатаю.

Почему так, и как это исправить?

Comment: а зачем вы вводите ctrl+j и ctrl+m, да ещё и **повторно** вводите пароль?

Comment: Я ввожу пароль и нажимаю Enter, но ничего не происходит, пробовал разные вырианты

Answer (score 1):

на запрос пароля вы вводите пароль и нажимаете <kbd>enter</kbd>.

пароль прочитан и отправлен программе (в данном случае — `git`). на этом — всё.

то, что вы **после** этого вводите, поступит на терминал и (если программа ещё продолжает работу) будет продублировано в `stdin` запущенной программе (`git`), которая, скорее всего, проигнорирует введённые символы.

Comment: про ctrl+j и ctrl+m странно вообще...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это аналоги `enter`.

Comment: Ввожу пароль нажимаю Enter и ничего не происходит. По ssh подключаюсь к хостингу nic, такая ерунда происходит только там, на других серверах все работает как надо.

Comment: @Devel0per, это совсем другой вопрос, никак не пересекающийся с тем, что вами был первоначально изложен. пожалуйста, либо внесите дополнение/изменение в ваш вопрос, нажав *править* под текстом вопроса, либо (лучше) задайте новый вопрос с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ого, 9000 преодолели. Поздравляю)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо!